# Rails 3 Passenger Path Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, apache, passenger, rack

Rails 3.2.10

Passenger 3.0.19

Ruby 1.9.3-p392 (using rbenv)

Trying to get my Rails app running on my server via Passenger. Getting this error:

> No such file to load -- path_to_app/app/assets/stylesheets/../config/environment

Here's my Apache conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName domain.com
DocumentRoot /srv/http
<Directory /srv/http>
    Allow from all
</Directory>

RackBaseURI /rails_app
RackEnv test
<Directory /srv/http/rails_app>
    Options -MultiViews
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

(where /srv/http/rails_app --> path_to_app/public)

I really have no idea why it's looking for a config file in the assets directory. This is config.ru (this is stock, as far as I know):

```
require ::File.expand_path('../config/environment',  __FILE__)
run RailsApp::Application
```

I've done this before, but only with Rails 2.x. Am I doing something wrong?

**UPDATE**: This happens even when trying to start a test or production server from the command line, so it's not passenger. A fresh Rails app works fine on all environments, so it has to be a migration or gem issue, but I don't even know where to start.

Comment: Word of caution (especially with Rails) - if you don't know what the problem, never assume an area, for example "must be migration or gem issue'.  My experience is that there's always a lot more possibilities than I first think of.

Comment: I suspect that this relates to stuff moving from /public to /assets (at least for the development environment) when the version went from 3.0 to 3.1, i.e. the "Asset Pipeline".  I suspect that your search may be started in /app then up a level to root, then down into config.  My advice would be to do a brand new app, then see what it has used for all such settings.   You might need to do one where you specifiy the version, e.g. `rails new _2.3.8_ app1` in order to have a valid comparitor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there were some weird FCGI files (dispatch.rb, dispatch.fcgi) kicking around in app/assets/stylesheets. Must have been leftover from when it was a Rails 2.x app or gotten moved there accidentally.